# Property "dynamicslotname" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Property "dynamicslotname" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. at  in vue3.
I am testing the dynamic slot of vue3, but i missing the question "Property "dynamicslotname" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. at "

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <base-layout>
    <template v-slot:[dynamicSlotName]>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </template>
  </base-layout>
</div>
</body>
<script>
  const baseLayout =  {
    template: `
    <div>
        <header>
          <slot name="header"></slot>
        </header>
    </div>
    `
  };
  const helloVue = {
    components: {
      baseLayout
    },
    data() {
      return {
        dynamicSlotName: "header"
      }
    }
  }
  Vue.createApp(helloVue).mount('#app')
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slot name should be written in lowercase not in `camelCase` like `dynamicslotname` instead of `dynamicSlotName`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <base-layout>
    <template v-slot:[dynamicslotname]>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </template>
  </base-layout>
</div>
</body>
<script>
  const baseLayout =  {
    template: `
    <div>
        <header>
          <slot name="header"></slot>
        </header>
    </div>
    `
  };
  const helloVue = {
    components: {
      baseLayout
    },
    data() {
      return {
        dynamicslotname: "header"
      }
    }
  }
  Vue.createApp(helloVue).mount('#app')
</script>
</html>
```

For more details please check https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/template-syntax.html#caveats